# как вытащить id группы в gitlab через data source

Tags: gitlab, terraform

с помощью Terraform создаю репозиторий в гитлаб и имею название группы 2326 в которую эта репа должна попасть как с помощью data вытащить айди группы 2326 -
вот Terraform config file -

```
# Configure the GitLab Provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source  = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "3.7.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.0.5"
}
# Add a token
provider "gitlab" {
  token    = var.gitlab_token
  base_url = "https://gitlab.myrepo.com/api/v4/"
}
# Add a project to the group
resource "gitlab_project" "myrepo-devops-tr_project" {
  name         = "myrepo-devops-tr_project"
  namespace_id = data.gitlab_group.id
  description = "issue for creating infrastructure resources"
  visibility_level = "public"
}
# Add a full_path
data "gitlab_group.id" "devops_users_repos" {
  full_path = "https://gitlab.myrepo.com/devops_users_repos/2326"
}
```

после отработки terraform plan  выскакивает ошибка -

```
Error: Invalid data source name
│ 
│   on main.tf line 24, in data "gitlab_group.id" "devops_users_repos":
│   24: data "gitlab_group.id" "devops_users_repos" {
│ 
│ A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае `full_path = group_name/user_id`, согласно правил оформления ответов на задания.

Так же, в сообщении об ошибке явно написано:

> A name must start with a letter or underscore **and may contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes**.

Имеется ввиду - `gitlab_group.id`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).